# What is the recommended setup.ini for SQL 2000 MSDE install?

Tags: sql-server

What is the recommended setup.ini for SQL 2000 MSDE install?

So far, I use:

```
[Options]
SAPWD=comp1exPa$$word
SECURITYMODE=SQL
INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
DATADIR ="C:\Databases"
COLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good enough.

However, it would be better if you used [SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx) 10 years after the first release of SQL 2000 and 4 years after it's last service pack...